# Sourcing a file before executing commands in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to install node js version using nvm using below Ansible yml file.

I get error like source "source /home/centos/.nvm/nvm.sh" file not found. But if I do the same by logging into the machine using ssh then it works fine.

```yaml
- name: Install nvm
  git: repo=https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git dest=~/.nvm version={{ nvm.version }}
  tags: nvm

- name: Source nvm in ~/.profile
  lineinfile: >
    dest=~/.profile
    line="source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh"
    create=yes
  tags: nvm

- name: Install node {{ nvm.node_version }}
  command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "source /home/centos/.nvm/nvm.sh"
    - nvm install {{ nvm.node_version }}
  tags: nvm
```

Error:

```
failed: [172.29.4.71] (item=source /home/centos/.nvm/nvm.sh) => {"cmd": "source /home/centos/.nvm/nvm.sh", "failed": true, "item": "source /home/centos/.nvm/nvm.sh", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}

failed: [172.29.4.71] (item=nvm install 6.2.0) => {"cmd": "nvm install 6.2.0", "failed": true, "item": "nvm install 6.2.0", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Regarding the "no such file" error:

`source` is an internal shell command (see for example [Bash Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html)), not an external program which you can run. There is no executable named `source` in your system and that's why you get `No such file or directory` error.

Instead of the `command` module use [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) which will execute the `source` command inside a shell.

---

### Regarding the sourcing problem:

In a `with_items` loop Ansible will run the shell twice and both processes will be independent of each other. Variables set in one will not be seen by the other.

You should run the two commands in one shell process, for example with:

```
- name: Install node {{ nvm.node_version }}
  shell: "source /home/centos/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install {{ nvm.node_version }}"
  tags: nvm
```

---

### Other remarks:

Use `{{ ansible_env.HOME }}` instead of `~` in the `git` task. Either one will work here, but tilde expansion is the functionality of shell and you are writing code for Ansible.

Comment: not able to run the command "source /etc/environment" using shell module also.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast You should use `.` to replace `source` using `bin/sh`.