# Impossible to source ~/.bash_aliases in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Using an alias in `~/.bash_aliases` while `$HOME=/home/ubuntu` as:

```
alias k="kubectl -s http:xxxx"
```

`k` here stands for **different commands** in different servers, I have to use this feature but I just cannot `source` it in Ansible shell module.

Is there any other ways around it?

I read several posts:

- [Sourcing a file before executing commands in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379083/sourcing-a-file-before-executing-commands-in-ansible)
- [can not source ~/.bashrc file with ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133810/can-not-source-bashrc-file-with-ansible)
- [Not possible to source .bashrc with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256884/not-possible-to-source-bashrc-with-ansible)

And tried:

#### No - 1

```
  shell: ". /home/ubuntu/.bash_aliases && k get pods --all-namespaces | grep {{ serviceName }}"
```

#### No - 2

```
  shell: ". /home/ubuntu/.bashrc && k get pods --all-namespaces | grep {{ serviceName }}"
```

#### Result

Both of the above tries give me this error:

```
"/bin/sh: 1: k: not found"
```

---

#### No - 3

```
  shell: "source /home/ubuntu/.bash_aliases && k get pods --all-namespaces | grep {{ serviceName }}"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

#### No - 4

```
  shell: "source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc && k get pods --all-namespaces | grep {{ serviceName }}"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

#### Result

Both of the above tries give me this error:

```
"/bin/bash: k: command not found"
```

#### No - 5

```
   shell: "sudo -u ubuntu -i k get pods --all-namespaces | grep {{ serviceName }}"
```

#### Result

```
"-bash: k: command not found"
```

#### No - 6

```
shell: ssh -t localhost /bin/bash -ci 'k get pods --all-namespaces | grep {{ serviceName }}'
```

#### Result

```
"Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.", "Host key verification failed."
```

#### No - 7

```
  shell: ssh -tt localhost /bin/bash -ci 'k get pods --all-namespaces | grep {{ serviceName }}'
  register: result
```

#### Result

```
"Host key verification failed."
```

### A Walk-Around Solution for Me

```
  vars:
    - kubeCommand: ""

  tasks:

    - name: Get Command Alias
      shell: cat ~/.bash_aliases  |  awk -F[\"] '{print $2}'
      register: result

    - set_fact: kubeCommand={{ result.stdout }}

    - name: Get service 
      shell: "{{ kubeCommand }} get pods --all-namespaces | grep {{ serviceName }}"
```

But the question still stands here.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's somewhat ugly, but you can put your `alias k="kubectl -s http:xxxx"` directly in `.bashrc` or `source .bash_aliases` from `.bashrc` and in your play you have to write:

```
shell: '/bin/bash -i -c "k get pods --all-namespaces | grep {{ serviceName }}"'
```

Comment: Your suggestions have been tried as the question mentioned using `source` for `bin/bash` and `.` for `/bin/sh` and other methods similar but your *shell command* `/bin/bash -i -c <my_command>` does work as expected. Thank you ~